# Updating custom timestap field in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update a custom timestamp field and therefore wrote this function

```
public function touchDelivery() {
    $this->delivery = $this->freshTimestamp();
    return $this->save();
}

public function pushSuccess($id) {
    return Message::where('id', '=', $id)->touchDelivery();
}
```

But when executing Laravel complains:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::touchDelivery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that this code is in your Eloquent file.
There's problem with `return Message::where('id', '=', $id)->touchDelivery();`

First you need to get all the messages and then for each messages, you need to call the method. Something like this.

```
public function pushSuccess($id) {
   $messages = Message::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
   foreach($messages as $message)
         $message->touchDelivery();
   ...
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.